# "more strongly"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is "more strongly" improper? Here's an example blurb:

"Looking back now, I don’t think my response would change that much. I might’ve spoken more strongly, but that’s about it."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is quite correct and perfectly phrased. Do not change a bit. Any attempt to couch it in more proper terms would make it seem stilted. Stick with your first choice.